# Why does this code output the same number multiple times?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

Running the following code multiple times produces output where the same number occurs more than once. I'm not sure why is that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>

using namespace std;

const int NUM_THREADS = 5;

void* thread_entry(void *i){
   cout<<(long)i<<endl;
}

int main () {
  pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];

  long i;
  for(i=0;i<NUM_THREADS;i++){
    pthread_create(&threads[i],NULL,&thread_entry,(void *)i);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

It is compiled with `g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -lpthread`.

The output:

```
$ ./a.out 
0
1
4
$ ./a.out 
014
14
23
$ ./a.out 
02
2
3
```

Comment: Did you consider joining your threads?

Comment: You need to join your threads, and you need a mutex or similar to protect your outputting to cout, wihch is currently interleaving values. You might also want to consider using std::thread.

Comment: I don't see how waiting for their termination would change their output

Comment: sure enough joining solves the multiple value problem, but unclear for me why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Main problems of this program are:

1. falling off the end of a function with a declared return type
2. not joining the threads
3. using std::cout from multiple threads without synchronization

3 is technically not necessary (if you fix 1 and 2) because output through std::cout by default is thread-safe, as in, not a data race, but the output can be interleaved.

Now, for the interesting part of the question

> the same number occures more than once. I'm not sure why is that.

Assuming you're using Linux or something similar, when the main function exists, it executes `exit` which, in the GNU C runtime, executes `__run_exit_handlers`, which then calls `_IO_cleanup`. The job of `_IO_cleanup` is to write out any unwritten output buffers. If that happens *while* one of your other threads is in the middle of writing, such as inside the `write(2)` system call, `_IO_cleanup` will look at the buffer state and see that it's still "full" (`_IO_file_write` in the thread would update the buffer position indicator when it returns from `write(2)`). So according to cleanup, the buffer isn't written yet, and it initiates its own `write(2)` system call on the same buffer.

Answer (score 1):

[Cubbi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/273767/cubbi) has the right answer here.  The real issue is not joining the threads.  I'll leave the rest here for reference:

You should be seeing the output in an unpredictable order, but it shouldn't be producing duplicate values.  In general `iostream`s are not thread safe:

From C++14: 27.2.3 [iostreams.threadsafety]

> Concurrent access to a stream object (27.8, 27.9), stream buffer object (27.6), or C Library stream (27.9.2)
>   by multiple threads may result in a data race (1.10) unless otherwise specified (27.4). [ Note: Data races
>   result in undefined behavior (1.10). — end note ]

However 27.4 gives an exception that applies in this case:

> FILEs, Concurrent access to a synchronized (27.5.3.4) standard iostream object’s formatted and unformatted in-
>   put (27.7.2.1) and output (27.7.3.1) functions or a standard C stream by multiple threads shall not result
>   in a data race (1.10). [ Note: Users must still synchronize concurrent use of these objects and streams by
>   multiple threads if they wish to avoid interleaved characters. — end note ]

Since `cout` is synchronized, this should be thread safe.

Comment: This isn't strictly accurate. You do need to synchronise your output if you expect to get anything intelligible printed, but the Standard says that accessing objects like cout from multiple threads is safe, even without explicit synchronisation.  So there is no UB here, at least as far as performing the output is concerned.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: I've added the relevant standard quote.

Comment: I don't have access to the standard on this machine, but what does 27.4 say?

Comment: He's using `std::cout` without disabling synchronization, which is thread-safe for output, in the same standard. It just doesn't guarantee meaningful output and doesn't protect against the termination problem.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: Good point. Maybe a bug in the implementation then.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's expected behaviour if you don't synchronise the output yourself. And who is downvoting this???

Comment: @NeilButterworth: I still get errors with valgrind even after joining threads, but this may be a false positive.  I can't reproduce the incorrect output when the threads are joined.

Answer (score 0):

In multithreading there is no guarantee that the code in a thread will run before or after the code in another thread without any synchronization mechanism between.

You have a main thread and other threads created by the main thread and you cannot expect the number 'i' will not be cout'ed *before* the main thread's for loop increase it.